# Issue while removing elements in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

When I remove the nodes which have zero children, it removes the entire branch starting from the head i.e. if I remove a leaf node from the right subtree, it removes the right branch and same for the left.

If I remove any child with 2 children, it replaces it with the leftmost node of the right subtree and then removes the entire right branch from where I am taking the leftmost node.

```
struct Node{
    struct Node *left;
    int value;
    struct Node *right;
};

typedef struct Node node;

node * removeEle(node **root, int value){
    if((*root) == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }else{
        if(value < (*root)->value && (*root)->left != NULL){
            (*root)->left = removeEle(&(*root)->left, value);
        }else if(value > (*root)->value && (*root)->right != NULL){
            (*root)->right = removeEle(&(*root)->right, value);
        }else{
            if((*root)->left == NULL && (*root)->right == NULL){
               return NULL;
            }else if((*root)->left == NULL && (*root)->right != NULL){
                return (*root)->right;
            }else if((*root)->left != NULL && (*root)->right == NULL){
                return (*root)->left;
            }
            else{
                node * check = leftMost(&(*root)->right);
                (*root)->value = check->value;
                (*root)->right = removeEle(&(*root)->right, check->value);
                return (*root);
            }
        }
        if((*root) == NULL){
            printf("Helloworld");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

node * leftMost(node **root){
    while((*root)->left != NULL){
        (*root) = (*root)->left;
    }
    return (*root);
}

void traversal(node *root){

    if(root == NULL)return;

    printf("%d\n", root->value);
    if(root->left != NULL) traversal(root->left);
    if(root->right != NULL) traversal(root->right);
} 

void add(node **root, int value){
    if((*root) == NULL){
        (*root) = createNode();
        (*root)->value = value;
    }

    if((*root)->value > value){
        if((*root)->left == NULL){
            (*root)->left = createNode();
            (*root)->left->value = value;
        }else{
            add(&((*root)->left), value);
        }
    }else if((*root)->value < value){
        if((*root)->right == NULL){
            (*root)->right = createNode();
            (*root)->right->value = value;
        }else{
            add(&((*root)->right), value);
        }
    }
}

node *createNode(){
    node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

This is my test case.

```
int main(){

    node *root = NULL;
    add(&root, 10);
    add(&root, 20);
    add(&root, 5);
    add(&root, 6);
    add(&root, 2);
    add(&root, 23);
    add(&root, 12);
    removeEle(&root, 10);
    traversal(root);
}
```

All the functions except removal, works fine.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I tried debugging it, but what happens is when I put a printf after recursive calls it gives me segmentation fault and when I put a if after recursive calls my code works, no matter even if its a simple if, nothing even related to code, still it works.
I have added the if condition in the remove code above which I mentioned here.

Comment: You get a segfault, so debug that: take a backtrace from it and figure out why it's happening.

Comment: It works for me. Not segfault.

Comment: One problem: In `main` you are not updating `root` with the return value of `removeEle` and in some paths the function does not return anything.

Comment: @kaylum I did root = removeEle(....), and when I do traversal it is not printing anything, probably it's making root = NULL, cause the method is probably returning NULL at some point.

Comment: How about "in some paths the function does not return anything"? Did you do anything about  that?

Comment: @kaylum I am not getting which paths are missing return statements? Can you please mention those paths?

Comment: `if(value < (*root)->value && (*root)->left != NULL)` and the `if` after that.

Comment: I made a few changes in the remove, I am assigning the return values to the required left or right child, do I need a return statement there and if so, what effect will it have?

Comment: Thank you everyone for help. I managed to figure it out.